# How to override default black color of itext's checkbox check?

Tags: itext7

Currently iText 7 does not allow easy/any way of setting the colour of a checkbox when checked as it is fixed in the source code:

```
    /**
 * Performs the low-level drawing operations to draw a checkbox object.
 *
 * @param canvas   the {@link PdfCanvas} of the page to draw on.
 * @param width    the width of the button
 * @param height   the width of the button
 * @param fontSize the size of the font
 * @param on       the boolean value of the checkbox
 */
protected void drawCheckBox(PdfCanvas canvas, float width, float height, float fontSize, boolean on) {
    if (!on) {
        return;
    }

    if (checkType == TYPE_CROSS) {
        DrawingUtil.drawCross(canvas, width, height, borderWidth);
        return;
    }
    PdfFont ufont = getFont();
    if (fontSize <= 0) {
        fontSize = approximateFontSizeToFitBBox(ufont, new Rectangle(width, height), text);
    }
    // PdfFont gets all width in 1000 normalized units
    canvas.
            beginText().
            setFontAndSize(ufont, fontSize).
            resetFillColorRgb().
            setTextMatrix((width - ufont.getWidth(text, fontSize)) / 2, (height - ufont.getAscent(text, fontSize)) / 2).
            showText(text).
            endText();
}
```

Is there a sane way of changing the checkbox checked colour that we are not aware of without having to extend the **PdfFormField** class and override the **drawCheckBox(...)** method just to replace the **resetFillColorRgb()** call with **setFillColor(ColorConstants.BLUE)**?

The problem with that approach in our case is that we also need to replace an existing checkbox in a pdf document which means we have to copy over all properties from that checkbox to the newly created checkbox of our PdfFormField subclass.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated :)

---

**EDIT:** Here's the temporary solution until iText provides an API or someone else figures out a better hack:

```
    private static void overrideCheckboxCheckedColor(PdfDocument pdfDocument, PdfFormField pdfFormField, Color color) {
    try {
        // Get "Yes" state appearance object
        PdfWidgetAnnotation pdfWidgetAnnotation = pdfFormField.getWidgets().get(0);
        PdfDictionary normalAppearanceObject = pdfWidgetAnnotation.getNormalAppearanceObject();
        PdfStream onStateObject = normalAppearanceObject.getAsStream(new PdfName("Yes"));

        // Extract font size
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) onStateObject.getOutputStream().getOutputStream();
        String outputStreamContent = outputStream.toString();
        Pattern fontSizePattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)^.*\\s+((\\d+\\.)?\\d+)\\s+Tf.*$");
        Matcher fontSizeMatcher = fontSizePattern.matcher(outputStreamContent);
        boolean fontSizeFound = fontSizeMatcher.find();
        float fontSize = fontSizeFound ? Float.parseFloat(fontSizeMatcher.group(1)) : 10F;

        // Get width, height, font & text
        PdfFormXObject xObjectOn = (PdfFormXObject) PdfXObject.makeXObject(onStateObject);
        float width = xObjectOn.getWidth();
        float height = xObjectOn.getHeight();
        PdfFont font = pdfFormField.getFont();
        String text = "4";

        // Override checked color
        PdfCanvas canvasOn = new PdfCanvas(onStateObject, new PdfResources(), pdfDocument);
        canvasOn.beginText()
                .setFontAndSize(font, fontSize)
                .setFillColor(color)
                .setTextMatrix((width - font.getWidth(text, fontSize)) / 2, (height - font.getAscent(text, fontSize)) / 2)
                .showText(text)
                .endText();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Message message = new FormattedMessage("Could not override '{}' field checked color", pdfFormField.getFieldName());
        LOG.error(message, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The canvas the box is drawn on here is the on-state appearance xobject. Have you considered to simply change the on appearance of your check box instead of replacing the whole checkbox form field?

Comment: @mkl Thank you for the comment - could you maybe point/show an example?

Comment: You satu you need to change the appearance of an existing box. Can you share a representative (for your input files) example pdf? There sometimes are weird side effects of some of design details which make changing appearances more difficult...

Comment: @mkl I edited the question and added a working temporary solution - it basically overrides the checked colour in a bit hacky way, but the best I could figure out with least amount of throwaway code ;)